# Xcode 4.2 — add derived files to project

Tags: xcode, xcode4, reference, xcode4.2, auto-generate

I'm using bison parser generator in my Xcode 4 project. I've written custom build rule for generating C++-source file from *.y grammar file:

```
/usr/local/bin/bison
--defines="${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.hpp"
--output="${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.cpp"
--verbose "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}"
```

As you can see, Xcode places generated files in `$DERIVED_FILES_DIR` folder. Now I need to export generated header file `grammar.hpp` with object files as library.

The problem is that Xcode doesn't allow export files, that aren't included in project.

The first solution, as it seems, is to create a group with absolute path set to `$DERIVED_FILES_DIR`. Well, it actually works until I change my build settings to build Release configuration, since `$DERIVED_FILES_DIR` is dependent on build settings.
The second solution is somehow set group path to literally variable, i.e.

```
path = $DERIVED_FILES_DIR
```

So far I've found two possible ways to do it: [How to reference files with environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820665/how-to-reference-files-with-environment-variables) and [File references relative to DERIVED_FILE_DIR in Xcode](http://www.benzado.com/blog/post/352/file-references-relative-to-derived_file_dir-in-xcode). Either way doesn't work for me.

Maybe someone knows better way to add generated files to project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best options are:

1. Generate the files in your SRCROOT
2. Generate the files in BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR

These both have "Relative to..." options that should allow you to add the files to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up generating files in `${SRCROOT}` directory with custom `make` build target using `Makefile` that handles regenerating derived files. I just added these generated files to project, and made all actual build target depend on this `make` target.